# Merge two sorted parts of an array with constant memory in O(n) time

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Assume we have an array of length *N* where the subarrays from *0* to *N/2* and *N/2* to *N* elements are sorted.  Is it possible to sort the whole array using constant memory in *O(N)* time?

Example of an array:

```
10, 20, 30, 40, 1, 2, 35, 60
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want in place merging. See [this](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:LNH-bxuo4koJ:www.sofsem.cz/sofsem06/data/prezentace/23/A/Kim-OnOptimalandEfficientInPlaceMerging.ppt+in+place+merging&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk) and [this](http://www.dcs.kcl.ac.uk/technical-reports/papers/TR-04-05.pdf). Also, searching google for "in place merging" will give you a lot of good results. The algorithms aren't easy to implement nor fast in practice, so usually no one bothers with them.