# A Memory-Adaptive Merge Algorithm?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Many algorithms work by using the [merge algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm) to merge two different sorted arrays into a single sorted array.  For example, given as input the arrays

```
1  3  4  5  8
```

and

```
2  6  7  9
```

The merge of these arrays would be the array

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

Traditionally, there seem to be two different approaches to merging sorted arrays (note that the case for merging linked lists is quite different).  First, there are out-of-place merge algorithms that work by allocating a temporary buffer for storage, then storing the result of the merge in the temporary buffer.  Second, if the two arrays happen to be part of the same input array, there are [in-place merge algorithms](http://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=inplace-merge) that use only O(1) auxiliary storage space and rearrange the two contiguous sequences into one sorted sequence.  These two classes of algorithms both run in O(n) time, but the out-of-place merge algorithm tends to have a much lower constant factor because it does not have such stringent memory requirements.

My question is whether there is a known merging algorithm that can "interpolate" between these two approaches.  That is, the algorithm would use somewhere between O(1) and O(n) memory, but the more memory it has available to it, the faster it runs.  For example, if we were to measure the absolute number of array reads/writes performed by the algorithm, it might have a runtime of the form n g(s) + f(s), where s is the amount of space available to it and g(s) and f(s) are functions derivable from that amount of space available.  The advantage of this function is that it could try to merge together two arrays in the most efficient way possible given memory constraints - the more memory available on the system, the more memory it would use and (ideally) the better the performance it would have.

More formally, the algorithm should work as follows.  Given as input an array A consisting of two adjacent, sorted ranges, rearrange the elements in the array so that the elements are completely in sorted order.  The algorithm is allowed to use external space, and its performance should be worst-case O(n) in all cases, but should run progressively more quickly given a greater amount of auxiliary space to use.

Is anyone familiar with an algorithm of this sort (or know where to look to find a description of one?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156599/merge-two-sorted-parts-of-an-array-with-constant-memory-in-on-time

Comment: @agksmehx- Thanks for the link.  However, I don't think that this is quite what I'm looking for.  I'm already aware that you can merge in O(1) extra space, and this question is mostly asking if there is a way to have a merge algorithm that does progressively better the more free space you give it, so that if you can get, say, 100MB of extra space for 500MB of data, you would merge faster than if you had 10MB for 500MB of data.

Comment: What are the inputs and outputs? I.e., are you writing into one of the input arrays or to a separate array? (I suspect the former, since if it's the latter then this isn't an issue.)

Comment: @MSN- The input arrays are part of the same buffer.  I just updated the question to address this; thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Seems relevant, but not an actual answer to the question:  http://akira.ruc.dk/~keld/teaching/algoritmedesign_f05/Artikler/04/Huang88.pdf

Comment: @Fantius- Thanks for the link!  However, I've already read that paper (the link to my in-place merge implementation is actually based on that paper), but it doesn't seem to talk about how to adapt to when more memory is available.

Comment: I think is better to ask this in cstheory.

Answer (score 10):

at least according to the documentation, the [in-place merge function in SGI STL](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/inplace_merge.html) is adaptive and "its run-time complexity depends on how much memory is available". The source code is available of course you could at least check this one.

Comment: While this definitely works, notice that this function degrades to O(n log n) in the worst case, while there exist worst-case O(n) in-place merge algorithms.  I'm hoping that there is something better than this, though O(n log n) is still very good.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: STL has `inplace_merge`, which will adapt to the size of the temporary buffer available. If the temporary buffer is at least as big as one of the sub-arrays, it's O(N). Otherwise, it splits the merge into two sub-merges and recurses. The split takes O(log N) to find the right part of the other sub array to rotate in (binary search).

So it goes from O(N) to O(N log N) depending on how much memory you have available.

Comment: Whereas this will certainly work, it has pathological behavior when all the items in `lhs` are larger than the smallest item in `rhs`. For example, an array like `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. In such cases, your algorithm becomes "copy `T` items from `rhs` to `temp`, move `lhs` down by `T` positions, copy `T` items from `temp` to newly created space.` You end up doing `(sizeof(lhs) * sizeof(rhs))/T` moves within the array, plus `2*(sizeof(rhs)/T)` moves from the array to temp and back. The algorithm is O(n^2), as you can see if `T == 1`.

Comment: @JimMischel, no, it's not moving `lhs`, it's copying from the front of `lhs` into the space left behind by `rhs`. So you copy each element from `lhs` at most twice; we don't move the array, just wrap the beginning around the end repeatedly.

If we moved `lhs`, it would be N^2. That's why we copy the data we are about to overwrite instead of moving the entire array.

Comment: Why did you remove your other algorithm?  Was it too complicated and the actual algorithm turned out to be simple?

Comment: @PeterO., yes. Original was too complicated. I don't think it's linear due to the additional copies in the worst case.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/inplace_merge/: there's nothing about size of internal buffer. Can its size be controlled? In portable way? Any useful links for additional info?

Comment: @AndyT, ah, the subtle implementation details of STL exposed through `get_temporary_buffer()`. That's where `inplace_merge`s temporary buffer comes from.